# How to handle mail delivery failure notice in a C# VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I'm working on an C# VSTO Outlook addin, that extracts some information out of received mails. For normal messages this works fine, but if it's a mail delivery notice it fails because it's not a mailitem.

```
foreach (Outlook.MailItem mail in outlookApp.ActiveExplorer().Selection)
    {
      //get some information
    }
```

The errormessage is:

> System.__ComObject can't be converted to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem E_NOINTERFACE

Is there any way to query information out of this type of mail?

Comment: What object is the active Selection Selection ?  It is a mailbox or a mailitem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to cast an NDR message to the [ReportItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.reportitem) class. The `ReportItem` object is similar to a `MailItem` object, and it contains a report (usually the non-delivery report) or error message from the mail transport system.

Unlike other Microsoft Outlook objects, you cannot create this object. Report items are created automatically when any report or error in general is received from the mail transport system.

Also I'd suggest using the `for` loop instead of 'foreach' so that you could release underlying COM objects instantly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I cast my item as ReportItem? I tried "Outlook.ReportItem rep = (Outlook.ReportItem) selection;" but this fails with the same error message.

Comment: Selection is a collection of Outlook items. Try to choose the first one and then cast it.